# Organize and merge JS files, Google Closure?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to merge all my plugins so I can change from this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugin1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugin2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugin3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugin4.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

to this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The main idea is to have a tool to "auto import" into my plugins.js file all the plugins I need for my websites and also minify them when compiling. I've been testing with Google Closure (downloadable Java version of the compiler) and I figured how to minify files but I can't import external files. So I'd like to ask you if you could maybe tell me if Google Closure is the tool I'm looking for or if I should use another tool or method.

With "auto import" I mean something like:

PLUGINS/HELLO.JS

```
function hello(name) {
    alert('Hello, ' + name);
}
```

PLUGINS.JS

```
@import hello.js
hello('New user');
```

I hope I made myself clear, I apologize if I messed up with my English.

Thanks!!

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/ManageClosureDependencies.

Answer (score 5):

I asked myself same question, and found no acceptable answer.
Only way to join many files is putting multiple "--js" params in command line:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js 1.js --js 2.js --js 3.js --js_output_file all.js
```

I tried put lines like this (which used in Closure Compiler service UI):

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @code_url 1.js
// @code_url 2.js
// @code_url 3.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
```

... in "main.js" and compile it - no effect. :(

Answer (score 2):

Use RequireJs with its optimization possibilities. Have a look here: http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

Closure-compiler can do exactly what you want, but only with Closure-library code because of it's use of `goog.require` calls. With jQuery code, the best it could do is compile ALL of your plugins together into a single file, but it wouldn't take into account actual usage.

Unfortunately, I don't know of anything that will do this for code in general.

*Note: This isn't expected to be the accepted answer for the question. The question asked specifically about Closure-compiler and I wanted to make sure at least somewhere it was stated that the compiler isn't going to work as desired.*

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: require.js solves automated dependency management, of course. But this may not be always optimal strategy, because it keeps a high number of requests as every script need one request to load (AFAIK, I'm not sure about that). Is there a possibility to merge all javascripts to one automatically, to minimize number of requests?